Connecting two lines based on their value in ArcGIS Pro
In ArcGIS Pro 3.3 I have a layer of non-continuous lines that I want to connect based on depth values. Each line has a depth field (e.g., 0.3, 0.5, 0.8). I need to connect each line to the next one according to the depth values.
For example, if one line has a depth of 0.5 and there are two lines opposite it with depths of 0.7 and 1.5, I want to connect the line with a depth of 0.5 to the line with a depth of 0.7. How can I achieve this? Any suggestions or tools that can help?


Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. While the software is capable of the task, you have a challenging bit of computational geometry ahead. If the gaps between features are regular, you can construct a point 3/4-7/8 of the way in the gap, then select all features 3/8-1/4 away, then choose the best candidate by logic, and construct a new segment from old endpoint to new startpoint. It's not difficult, per se, but it is an exacting task. Unfortunately, this isn't the sort of problem we're geared to address, so you'll need to make an attempt, and detail any issue.

Are they always roughly parallel as you show? What if you have a third line coming in at a tangent with the same depth value, how do plan to reconcile that scenario?

Use feature vertices to points (both ends). Generate Near table, don't limit to closest, but limit to search distance (with locations). Bring points depths to that table using join field for in_fid near_fid. Delete  'negative slopes'. Use xy to line
